# MuleSoft WebService Consumer Connector : Could not dispatch soap message using the [HTTP_Request_configuration] HTTP configuration

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I am trying to consume a SOAP webservice using WebService Consumer Connector on MuleSoft.

However, I keep getting error

```
"Error dispatching message with config [HTTP_Request_configuration]:Could not dispatch soap message using the [HTTP_Request_configuration] HTTP configuration".
```

The same wsdl/service works using .Net Framework applciation.
I am running Anypoint Studio 7.15 and Mule runtime 4.4

Comment: Please share the configurations (Web Service Consumer and HTTP Requester if any) and flow with enough context to understand how the data for the request is constructed(as text XML). A [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be better. Also the full error message lines with details. Usually Mule errors span several lines of information, not just the error message. Then enable HTTP Wire logging to log the actual HTTP request. Do something similar in the .Net application to be able to compare both requests and understand the difference.